# Treeview Nested in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, treeview

I have dynamically added a TreeView to a cell in a GridView Control. The problem is the initial entry in the first node of the TreeView can be quite long. When the page is rendered the TreeView ends up increasing the size of my GridView column width because the first node does not wrap to the next line.

When I view the source HTML the table cell created by the TreeView for the first node looks like this:

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;"> </td>
```

The style is being generated dynamically by the TreeView control and I am wondering how I can override this?

I have tried using CSS but I believe the inline code overrides everything in the CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the NodeWrap property to True when you create your TreeView.  That will stop that CSS from being generated.